# What am I doing wrong? Python Reading and Distinguishing

Tags: python

Write a program that reads from an input file called "distances.txt" formatted like the following:

```
John Smith 5 mi  
Mary Jones 8 km  
Jack Washington 3.8 mi  
Jill Adams 9.1 km
```

Your program should output to a file called "winner.txt" the full name of the person with the longest distance.

What I have so far

```
def read(fileName):
    list2 =[]  
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        words[2] = float(words[2])
        if words[3] == "mi":
            words[2] = words[2] / 0.62137
            words[3] = "km"
            words[2] = float("{0:.1f}".format(words[2]))
        else:
            pass
        list2.append(words[2])
    maximum = max(list2)
    infile.close()
return

def rinter(fileName, maximum):
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        if maximum in line:
            print(line)

    fileName = read("distances.txt")
    newcode = rinter(fileName,maximum)

    print(fileName)
```

Comment: So what is the problem? any errors?

Comment: I am only getting the first function returned nothing else

Comment: @Slowtailes i edit the answer and add a complete answer , you can check it out ,

Comment: @Kasra Is there any way I could do it without the lambda function? I am not too familiar with them

Comment: yes , you can use a list comprehension , i will add it to answer soon !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that variables inside the functions has local scope , you need to return the `maximum` in `read` function then put it as the argument of `rinter` function :

```
def read(fileName):
    list2 =[]  
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        words[2] = float(words[2])
        if words[3] == "mi":
            words[2] = words[2] / 0.62137
            words[3] = "km"
            words[2] = float("{0:.1f}".format(words[2]))
        else:
            pass
        list2.append(words[2])
    maximum = max(list2)
    infile.close()
    return maximum


def rinter(fileName, maximum):
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        if maximum in line:
             print(line)

maximum = read("distances.txt")
newcode = rinter("winner.txt",maximum)
```

but this code just add the distance to `winner` file , if you need to add the full name you need to do it with another algorithm , you need to save a list of splited lines but sliced from first to index 2 then for find the max use `max` function with a lambda function as its `key` that find the max based on 2th index ! and then for write it to your file join the indices with `join` function :

```
def read(fileName):
    list2 =[]  
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        words[2] = float(words[2])
        if words[3] == "mi":
            words[2] = words[2] / 0.62137
            words[3] = "km"
            words[2] = float("{0:.1f}".format(words[2]))
        else:
            pass
        list2.append(words[:2])
    maximum = max(list2,key=lambda x:x[2])
    infile.close()
    return maximum


def rinter(fileName, maximum):
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    infile.write(' '.join(maximum))
    print('winner is :'+' '.join(maximum))

maximum = read("distances.txt")
newcode = rinter("winner.txt",maximum)
```

if you dont want to use `lambda` (as you say in comment) you can use list comprehension :
so replace the following line :

```
maximum = max(list2,key=lambda x:x[2])
```

with :

```
maximum = [l for l in list2 if l[2]==max(zip(*list2)[2])][0]
```

`zip(*list2)` give you the list of columns of `list2` so `zip(*list2)[2]` is list of distances then `max(zip(*list2)[2])` is max distance that you use it for the condition of choose the max list ! and the last `[0]` is because the result of the above code is a nested list with one index `[[]]` that you need the inner list ! but hardly i recommend that use the `max` function with `lambda` , that has more performance and is more **pythonic**

Comment: How does this return person's full name, and writes an output file?

Comment: @Marcin i just refine what that OP wanted to do , i miss the question , i'll edit the answer ! thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1):

Some changes to your code:

```
list1 = []       # contain names
list2 = []       # contain distance
def read(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        list1.append(" ".join(words[0:2]))
        words[2] = float(words[2])
        if words[3] == "mi":
            words[2] = words[2] / 0.62137
            list2.append(float(words[2]))
       else:
           list2.append(float(words[2]))

    infile.close()
read("distances.txt")
maximum = max(list2)
winner = list1[list2.index(maximum)]
print(winner,maximum,"km")
f = open('winner.txt','w')
f.write(winner+" "+ str(mamimum)+" km")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to cast string to double:

```
words[2] = words[2] / 0.62137
```

You have to return maximum value or declare it as global variable.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed your read function. now it returns person name and its distance:

```
def read(fileName):
    list2 =[]
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        #print(words)
        words[2] = float(words[2])
        if words[3] == "mi":
            words[2] = words[2] / 0.62137
            words[3] = "km"
            words[2] = float("{0:.1f}".format(words[2]))
        else:
            pass
        list2.append((' '.join(words[0:2]), words[2]))
    maximum = max(list2, key=lambda v: v[1])
    #print(list2, maximum)
    infile.close()
    return maximum

person_name, distance = read("data.csv")
print(person_name, distance)
#Jill Adams 9.1
```

Not sure what function `rinter` should be doing though.

To save the results in an output file, you can:

```
with open("winner.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(person_name + ' ' + str(distance))
```